# Is there a difference between calling a member function from a leaf class in or out of the destructor body?

Tags: c++, runtime-error, virtual-destructor

I have a specific case which is hard to isolate in a code snippet here but I can explain it...

I have a class A : public B and A has a member pointer of some type foo * f. In the virtual destructor for A, I have something like:

```
A::~A() { shutdown(); }
```

where, shutdown is nonvirtual and looks something like:
void A::shutdown() {delete f;}

it turns out at runtime this gives me a "pure virtual method called terminate called without an active exception Aborted (core dumped)" but if I remove shutdown() from the body of the destructor and call it directly, and then let the destructor run...I no longer get this...

What could possibly be causing behavior of this sort? I've tried stepping with gdb but it's huge and I'm not even sure what to look for. Any ideas would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you rule out trying to free memory from an invalid pointer?

Comment: Yes because shutdown then destructor works but shutdown in destructor doesnt..it's not the pointer that is flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `shutdown` is a pure virtual function somewhere up the inheritance tree, or it calls another member function which is pure virtual somewhere up the inheritance tree. Either directly or indirectly, but that's what happens.

Check the execution path to see where the call is made and get rid of it.

Comment: Well shutdown is a nonvirtual function that I defined, i can even rename it to something else...all it calls is delete f..i dont understand why doing this outside the leaf class destructor and then letting the empty destructor for the leaf class be called right after that would be different from letting the destructor of the leaf class be called, which deletes f...

Comment: Does the destructor for f call back into A? Take a stack trace, that should identify the culprit quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If A has both the shutdown method AND the pointer f, don't call shutdown() at all. Just delete f in the destructor directly.

Comment: What I just noticed is that other destructors are being called before that destructor is called upon returning from main..some of those are for objects which I am guessing cause the problem because they are somehow tied to this A object...by calling shutdown directly, it does some stuff before ANY destructors are ever called..this doesnt crash but I am still checking it is not a bug..thanks!